# Visual Studio 2013 C# compile with /main

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to write a code for a port scanner. When I click *Build* I'm getting the following error messages...I realize it's the same error just in two different locations, but I figured it would hurt to list both:

> Error    1    Program 'c:\Users\pat_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\obj\Debug\WpfApplication2.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'PortScanner.Program.Main(string[])'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.
>
> Error    2    Program 'c:\Users\pat_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\obj\Debug\WpfApplication2.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'WpfApplication2.App.Main()'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

Here is my code:

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace PortScanner
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool stop = false;
        static int startPort;
        static int endPort;

        static List<int> openPorts = new List<int>();

        static object consoleLock = new object();

        static int waitingForResponses;

        static int maxQueriesAtOneTime = 100;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        begin:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the IP Address of the target:");
            string ip = Console.ReadLine();

            IPAddress ipAddress;

            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out ipAddress))
                goto begin;

        startP:

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the starting port to start scanning on:");
            string sp = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!int.TryParse(sp, out startPort))
                goto startP;

        endP:

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the end port:");
            string ep = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!int.TryParse(ep, out endPort))
                goto endP;

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop scanning...");

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartScan, ipAddress);

            Console.ReadKey();

            stop = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void StartScan(object o)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = o as IPAddress;

            for (int i = startPort; i < endPort; i++)
            {
                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    int top = Console.CursorTop;

                    Console.CursorTop = 7;
                    Console.WriteLine("Scanning port: {0}    ", i);

                    Console.CursorTop = top;
                }

                while (waitingForResponses >= maxQueriesAtOneTime)
                    Thread.Sleep(0);

                if (stop)
                    break;

                try
                {
                    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,     SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                    s.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, i), EndConnect,  s);

                    Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingForResponses);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        static void EndConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                DecrementResponses();

                Socket s = ar.AsyncState as Socket;

                s.EndConnect(ar);

                if (s.Connected)
               {
                    int openPort =      Convert.ToInt32(s.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[1]);

                    openPorts.Add(openPort);

                    lock (consoleLock)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected TCP on port: {0}", openPort);
                    }

                    s.Disconnect(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        static void IncrementResponses()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingForResponses);

            PrintWaitingForResponses();
        }

        static void DecrementResponses()
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref waitingForResponses);

            PrintWaitingForResponses();
        }

        static void PrintWaitingForResponses()
        {
            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                int top = Console.CursorTop;

                Console.CursorTop = 8;
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for responses from {0} sockets       ", waitingForResponses);

                Console.CursorTop = top;
            }
        }
    }
}
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
         public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously want to write a ConsoleApplication. You picked WpfApplication. Copy your whole code, create a new project based on ConsoleApplication and paste your code there.

And try to get rid of the `goto`s; it's not BASIC. You could easily make a single function for all your three uses.

Comment: Thank You... Again I'm new to programming and didn't know how the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in your other solution files to see if there's another Main() defined somewhere else that is just confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In a WPF application, `Main()` is automatically created for you. Since you also provided your own, that is why you are getting the conflict. To fix this:

- Right-click App.xaml in the solution explorer, select Properties
- Change 'Build Action' to 'Page'

Comment: I did this and it now builds correctly, however when I try to run the program nothing happens.